# How to run your .net console application to add bingmapapi key to sharepoint 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I saw a [post](http://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2013/05/set-the-bing-maps-api-key-in-office-365-using-csom-to-leverage-sharepoint-2013-geolocation-features/) on how to register Bing Maps API key on Sharepoint Online using this simple .NET console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var webUrl = new Uri("<Office 365 site URL>");
    using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
    {
        var login = "<Office 365 login email>";
        var password = "<Office 365 password>";
        var secureStrPwd = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            secureStrPwd.AppendChar(c);
        }

        var creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, secureStrPwd);
        ctx.Credentials = creds;

        var web = ctx.Web;
        web.AllProperties["BING_MAPS_KEY"] = "<Bing maps API key>";
        web.Update();

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

I don't know anything on .NET and I have Visual Studio 2010. What are the steps required to run this code in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

To run that code in VS 2010, follow steps in [Creating a Basic SharePoint Foundation Client Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539974%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

(0. Open Visual Studio, close all dialogs opened automatically)

> 1. On the File menu, point to New and click Project.
> 2. In the New Project dialog box, select [...] Visual C# in the
>      Installed Templates panel. Select Windows and then Console
>      Application. Choose .NET Framework 3.5 from the drop-down at the top
>      of the center panel. Type a name and location for the project in the
>      Name and Location boxes. Then click OK.
> 3. In Windows Explorer, copy the two DLLs from the server's
>      %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
>      extensions\14\ISAPI folder into the top-level folder of your console
>      application.
> 4. Right-click the project in Solution Explorer, click Add Reference, and
>      in the Add Reference dialog box, click the Browse tab and navigate to
>      the folder where you copied Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll. Select the two DLLs, and
>      click OK.

5. Then replace empty `main` with a code you cited.

> 6. Press F5 to run the application...